# Render partial with ajax and route url

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am creating a dynamic user profile.  I want to render partials using ajax (to avoid page reloads).

When I am rendering partial via ajax, for example `Profile/sections/skills` I am getting partial (*my controller returns partial view*) and rendering `#partials div`.

The problem is when I hit the route directly by manually typing in the browser `Profile/sections/skills` it returns only partial html.

I want both to work correctly: render partial via call with ajax and when I type in the url it can be found.

#### html

```
<div class="profile-navbar">
            <ul class="ul-menu">
                <li class="space"></li>
                <li class="active"> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> About</a> </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="skills"> <i class="fa fa-robot"></i> Skills/a>
                </li>

                <li> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-images"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> CV</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Experience </a></li>

            </ul>
    </div>


<div id="partials"> </div>
```

#### js

```
 $('.profile-navbar ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Skills", "Profile")',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response, status) {

            $("#partials").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

#### Controller

```
[Route("Profile/Skills")]
public IActionResult Skills()
{
    return PartialView("Skills");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a partial view defined for your `[Route("Profile/Skills")]`.

To accomplish what you want you need to do the following:

**Define a regular view for the same route**

This view will contain a reference to your partial so the partial is rendered within the larger HTML of the full view (when the route is called directly).

**Modify Controller Action to check for Ajax**

Once you have a regular view and the partial view then you can modify your controller action to conditionally decide whether to:

- renderpartial (if the caller is Ajax)
- or render the full view (if it is not an ajax call)

**IsAjaxRequest() method**

In past versions of ASP.NET MVC there was a method on the `Request` object called `IsAjaxRequest()`.  When this method is available your controller action code could be as simple as:

```
[Route("Profile/Skills")]
public IActionResult Skills()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("Skills");
    else
        return View();
}
```

**ASP.NET Core is missing IsAjaxRequest() method**

Unfortunately it seems that this method was overlooked in ASP.NET Core (as best as as I tell at the present time).  But it also seems that the underlying code was simple enough that many people have managed to duplicate its behavior without much trouble.

If `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` is not available to you because of ASP.NET core you should be able to duplicate its behavior in your controller action something like this:

```
[Route("Profile/Skills")]
public IActionResult Skills()
{
    bool isAjaxCall = Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"]=="XMLHttpRequest";
    if (isAjaxCall)
        return PartialView("Skills");
    else
        return View();
}
```

A more formalized and reusable approach to the dealing with missing `IsAjaxRequest()` method is described in this [post](https://dotnetthoughts.net/detecting-ajax-requests-in-aspnet-core/)